# Can someone explain how the Presentational Layer specifically communicates with the Service Layer?

Tags: javascript, wcf, dto

Can someone explain how the Presentational Layer communicates with the Service Layer?

I know I have to use these things to make this magic happen (WCF, DTO, and Javascript), but I'm not exactly sure how to fit it all together.

WCF - Windows communication foundation - MS technology for building service oriented applications

DTO - Data transfer object - special type of object used to tranport data from one layer/tier to other layer/tier.

I'm using aspx, javascript for my presentational layer, which is not too much different from html. So I guess the question is how can I use javascript to communicate through DTO's to my WCF service layer?

My Architecture:

---

|  Presentational Layer (aspx)   |

---

---

|  Service Layer (Uses WCF)  |

---

---

|  Business Layer (Uses C#)   |

---

---

|  Data Access Layer |

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use JavaScript, you will have much better luck writing SOAP web services instead - which can be easily done in C#.

WCF is best when the provider and consumer are both written in .net.

Box 1 (Web Services Server) Layers

- Exposed Services (WCF Web Service Provider)
- Business (C#)
- Data Access

Box 2 (Web Server) Layers

- View (ASPX/Javascript)
- Controler (C#)
- Model (WCF Web Service Consumer)

MSDN Examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx